# Cyrus' Adventure (Part 9)

Tags: steganography

After pressing the button, the walls opened. This time, instead of a damp smelly room, a futuristic lab appeared.

"What the-" exclaimed Cyrus.

T.E.D. scanned the whole lab quickly.

Cyrus couldn't believe what he saw, since he was exploring ruins inside a deep forest. However, he could only look around.

Inside the lab were some uncanny specimens of unknown creatures. Cyrus found a picture on the wall.

"Hey! T.E.D.! Can you help me scan this picture?" He asked.

"Yes. Master," T.E.D. answered.

T.E.D. scanned the whole picture.

He told Cyrus, "This is a steganographic photo. Maybe Master can use a laptop."

T.E.D. pulled a laptop out of his belly.

Cyrus looked at the photo. What should he do?

[image]

Hint:

> Don't think too                                            far away

Comment: rot13: Jung guerr ynlref? Qba'g nyjnlf or fb natel :)

Comment: If no one answers until Wednesday, I will answer it by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nobody is answering it anymore, I am going to answer it myself.
If you examine the first picture, you get a bit.ly link (*bit* + 2Ywy6OQ) which is

> http://bit.ly/2Ywy6OQ

After you find this picture, it tells you to 'cut the picture in two halves'.
So do what it tells you to do!

---

The answer is

> Cut the picture in two halves (referring to the first one)

Comment: Oh.  I was looking for the steganography tag.

Comment: @K Sharing Oh!The answer of "What  should he do ?" is  to cut the picture into two halves (+1) :)

Comment: The bit.ly link is already related to steganography :)

Answer (score 6):

Partial to get someone started:

> 2Ywy6OQ is a "bit" interesting

It is a:

> http://bit.ly/2Ywy6OQ ... It leads to an image hosted on Imgur.

Comment: Got many BYTES from that bit(+1)!

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer

First Step:

> [This bit.ly link](http://bit.ly/2Ywy6OQ) (hinted by "bit") leads you to the next picture (posted by LeppyR64, found by me independently

Second Step:

Attempts:

> 1. Opening the .png in Notepad - to no avail
>  2. Opening it in Photoshop - to no avail, i think
>  3. Opening it in GIMP - found three layers

Comment: Rot5: Knwxy xyju htwwjhy, xjhtsi xyju bwtsl

Comment: Rot14: Wh wg bch hvoh qcadzwqohsr